# R: Unable to download PNG image from secure site

Tags: r, https, web-scraping, rcurl, httr

I'm trying to download a PNG image from a url that is `HTTPS`, requires a `login` and `cookies`.

Attempting from my browser I'm able to easily download the image.

However, I return the following error in R

```
download.file(URL, dest = "test.png")

trying URL 'https://url.png'
Error in download.file(URL, dest = "test.png") : 
  cannot open URL 'https://url.png'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(URL, dest = "test.png") :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

*note actual url omitted for privacy concerns*

I've attempted using `httr` and `RCurl` without much luck.

### Attempts

```
## Provided `user/pass` as well as `user_agent` so site thinks i'm a browser, not robot
library(httr)    
url <- "https://url.png"
html <- GET(url, authenticate("user", "pass"), user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"))
html

Response [https://url.png]
  Date: 2016-03-22 11:46
  Status: 403
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 4.18 kB
```

Comment: I still can not reproduce since no URL/user/passwd provided. Usually you use a `POST()` to send the user/passwd and receive the cookie(s), then you `GET()` the url providing the cookie(s) with `set_cookies()`.